# Is there a way to assign a default image to an option in Option Templates?

Tags: magento-1.5

I have created several custom option templates, all of which have images that I have loaded for each value in a given option.

[image: values with images]

However, what I want to do is have a default image for the option that will show until an option is selected. I know that I can set an option to be selected by default. That works fine but we do not want to preselect an option for a customer in this way. Unfortunately, if we do not have a value selected for the option, then no image shows up as shown in the image below.

[image: values on front end]

Obviously I can include some text in the **Note** field for the option, but I also need a way to include a default image in the **General Information** screen (shown below) and I have no idea how to add that functionality.

[image: values on front end]

Thanks to anyone who can/will help with this issue.